# Develop flutter app without actually installing flutter in my machine

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My laptop stopped working and i really need to work on a flutter app. I have this old  laptop that is 32 bit and i found out that we can not install flutter in 32 bit systems.
So is there any way i can still work on my flutter app using my 32 bit laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy a cheap EC2 instance on AWS with the config you need. Also, Flutter as of now works on CodePen so you can write and see the output online.

Another fancy method will be to use an online code editor ( my suggestion [Visual Studio Code online](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/visual-studio-codespaces/)) and create a repository on github or other VCS host and finaly connect this to a CI/CD pipeline like Codemagic that will mail you the build outputs (apk and app). You can test your code in codepen before running throught the pipeline

Comment: If your query is resolved, I would request to mark the correct answer and close the question